# How to search for a file extension (.xls) and change it's name? C#

Tags: c#, windows

The product I'm using is a Beijer HMI, currently i can generate a report and save it to a known location (my desktop - C:\Users\mrdav\Desktop).

I need to be able to search on my desktop for a file extension .xls and change its name.

When the report is generated by the HMI, it uses the date and time which means when the file is generated the name will be different every time.

On the press of a button i need to search my desktop for the .xls file and change its name to a variable.

// This is my variable with my program

string NewName = Globals.Tags.Tag1.Value;

The code that is generated needs to sit within the below example.

```
public partial class Screen1
{

    void Button1_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        // Code to be added here... 
    }


}
```

Hopefully someone can help, I’m using windows compact framework so limited on functionality.

Any questions please let me know.

Thanks in advance,

Dave

Comment: Please include the minimum amount of text in your question to describe the problem and clarify the question

Comment: Hi Eugene.. thanks for the feedback hopefully my edit will make more sense to you. Please let me know if you need more info. All the best. D

Comment: The directory this file is dropped in, is it dedicated to that product or is it literally dropping somewhere as open as the desktop? How frequently are files being dropped here? How often and how will you be running this script?

Comment: I have edited my original post to answer a question of yours. The product im using is a Beijer HMI. The code will be activated on a button press to change the file name from 10.10.10.xls to "tagvalue".xls and to be saved in the same location for now.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example how you can do that:

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(sExportPath);
FileInfo[] Files = dir.GetFiles("*.csv"); 
foreach(FileInfo file in Files )
{
   // rename file
   System.IO.File.Move(file.FullName, GenerateNewFileName());
}
//elsewhere in the class
private string GenerateNewFileName()
{
    //here is where you implement creating or getting the filename that you want your file to be renamed to. An example might look like the below
    string serialNumber = GetSerialNumber(); //Get the serial number that you talked about in the question. I've made it a string, but it could be an int (it should be a string)
    return Path.ChangeExtension(serialNumber,".xls"); //to use path you will need a using statement at the top of your class file 'using System.IO'
}
```

Comment: Thank you Eugene,

do i add the variable i need here (VarName)

System.IO.File.Move(file.FullName, GenerateNeFileName(Var Name));

Very new to this sorry.

Comment: GenerateNewFileName() is a method (that you need to create) that will generate the filename you want to to rename the file to.

Comment: Ive tried to implement your code but it wont allow the new method. I have edited my orginal question so you can see what the format is.

Above that code i have included System.IO;

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work...but i know its not as tidy as it could be.

Any suggestions?

Thanks to all that helped, got there in the end!

```
    void Button_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
        // Location for new file
            string NewFileName = @"c:\users\mrdav\desktop\testfolder\";
        // Add varibale name to new file
            NewFileName += Globals.Tags.Tag1.Value;
        // add .xls extention to new file
            NewFileName += ".xls";
        //show new file name to check all ok
            MessageBox.Show (NewFileName);
        //search for .xls in known directory
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\users\mrdav\desktop");
            FileInfo[] Files = di.GetFiles("*.xls");
        // if files exist with .xls extention
            foreach(FileInfo file in Files )
            {
            // show full file name
                MessageBox.Show (file.FullName);
            //rename old file to new file name and move to new folder
                File.Move(file.FullName, NewFileName);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)

        {
            MessageBox.Show (ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```